# How to get the type of unsecable "int toto" for use in preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, code-generation

I use macros to DECLARE functions like:

```
NATIVE(int, myfunctionname, int param1, int param2)
NATIVE(int, myfunctionname, int param1, int)
```

The 'NATIVE' macro is responsible for generating a wrapper like:

```
int myfunctionname(int arg0, int arg1) {
   return mystruct.myfunctionname(arg0, arg1);
}
```

for some specific reasons, I can't use LD_PRELOAD or the ld --wrap command.

The main problem I have now is to be able to retrieve at compile time the type "int" both when the preprocessor token is "int" or when it is "int param0".

EDIT: I would like to be able to use both:

```
NATIVE(int, myfunctionname, int param1, int param2)
NATIVE(int, myfunctionname, int, int)
```

but only the latter works. As asked in the comments here is more context:

```
#define c99_count(...)    _c99_count1 (, ## __VA_ARGS__) /* If only ## worked.*/
#define _c99_count1(...)  _c99_count2 (__VA_ARGS__,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
#define _c99_count2(_,x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,n,...) n

#define FULL_ARGS_0()
#define FULL_ARGS_1(X0)  X0 a0
#define FULL_ARGS_2(X0,X1)  X0 a0, X1 a1
#define FULL_ARGS_3(X0,X1,X2)  X0 a0, X1 a1, X2 a2
#define FULL_ARGS_4(X0,X1,X2,X3)  X0 a0, X1 a1, X2 a2, X3 a3
#define FULL_ARGS_5(X0,X1,X2,X3,X4)  X0 a0, X1 a1, X2 a2, X3 a3, X4 a4

#define _ARGS_0()
#define _ARGS_1(X0)  a0
#define _ARGS_2(X0,X1)   a0, a1
#define _ARGS_3(X0,X1,X2)  a0, a1, a2
#define _ARGS_4(X0,X1,X2,X3)  a0, a1, a2, a3
#define _ARGS_5(X0,X1,X2,X3,X4) a0, a1, a2, a3, a4

#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT (a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__

/*
 gives a name X0 a0
 */
#define  FULL_ARGS(...) CAT ( FULL_ARGS_, c99_count (__VA_ARGS__) ) (__VA_ARGS__)
#define  ARGS(...) CAT (_ARGS_,c99_count (__VA_ARGS__)) (__VA_ARGS__)

#define NATIVE(rtype, name,...)                                    \
  rtype name (FULL_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  {                                                             \
    return (*g_libc.name ## _fn) (ARGS (__VA_ARGS__));              \
  }
```

Comment: Well, for simple types like you show, just drop the "param*n*" from the arguments.  The problem is with types like `int (param1&)[4]` where the parameter needs to go *inside* the type.

Comment: I know I can solve this by removing "param n" but I was looking for a more robust option. My question is "is it possible to get away without dropping 'param n'" via template machinery or decltype etc... Otherwise it means I have to change hundreds of lines in an upstream project, which is not a fun job or a fun change to take in for the project.

Comment: I'm not sure how retrieving `int` helps here. Don't you mean retrieving `param1`, `param2`, etc ?

Comment: Can you show more of what you want to do please.

Comment: retrieving either would work. If I can retrieve the type, then it's finished, If I can retrieve param1, then I can call decltype on it to get its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace detail_paramType {
    template <class>
    struct unpackType;

    template <class T>
    struct unpackType<void(T)> { using type = T; };
}

#define PARAM_TYPE(...) \
    typename detail_paramType::unpackType<void(__VA_ARGS__)>::type
```

That was a bit tricky. Syntaxes like `using type = void (*param)();` don't compile, because the type shan't contain a name.

The variable declaration syntax is compatible, but gets us no closer to the goal, as we don't know the parameter's name:

```
void (*param)(); // Fine
using type = decltype(???); // Now what ? We can't name param...
```

However, names are allowed (and ignored) inside the syntax of a function type's parameters. So `PARAM_TYPE` stuffs its parameter inside a function type, and passes it to `unpackType`, which deduces the parameter's type back. No need to know the parameter's original name, and it works for any type.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d78394f1352dd02)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is smart indeed. Its has problems when the prototype contains variadic arguments ( "...") but I guess that can't be helped so I accept the answer :) Thanks again

Comment: @mattator could you expand (haha) on that problem ?

Comment: For instance I have NATIVE(int, open64, const char *path, int flags, ...); which gives:
../model/libc.cc:59:63: error: ‘type’ in ‘struct detail_paramType::unpackType<void(...)>’ does not name a type
     typename detail_paramType::unpackType<void(__VA_ARGS__)>::type

Comment: @mattator That makes sense, as `T` cannot match a vararg. What you can do is add a specialization `template <>
    struct unpackType<void(...)> { /* ... */ };` to match that case, and decide what you do from there.